# Column 'code' in where clause is ambigous

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need a bit help with a query. I want extract the content from three different table, this table have different records so the `code` key is different agains the other table. The table contains the credentials for the login, I need to check if the code and the email is found in almost one table, this is an example:

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM login_tb1, login_tb2, login_tb3
                  WHERE (code = '".mysql_real_escape_string($code)."') OR 
                        (email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."') ";
```

Now when I execute this query I get this error:

> Column 'code' in where clause is ambigous

I can't perform a JOIN 'cause the column code is different, all the records are different. All the table have the same structure anyway. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `Table.column`

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to understand that error message as well. Ambigous is such a fancy word. In human language, it means that MySQL is trying to tell you: *"Hey man, the column exists in multiple tables in the select clause, so I don't know which table you mean!"*. You should be explicit about the table:

```
$Query = "SELECT * FROM login_tb1, login_tb2, login_tb3
                  WHERE (login_tb1.code = '".mysql_real_escape_string($code)."') OR 
                        (login_tb1.email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."') ";
```

If you don't care about which table and they have the same schema, you still need to be explicit, so your query will be a bit more advanced:

```
SELECT * FROM login_tb1 as l1, login_tb2 as l2, login_tb3 as l3
WHERE ( l1.code = 'code' OR l1.email = 'email' )
  OR  ( l2.code = 'code' OR l2.email = 'email' )
  OR  ( l3.code = 'code' OR l3.email = 'email' )
```

**Side note:** I don't know your exact use case, but it seems a bit like an anti-pattern that you have multiple login tables with the seemingly same schema. Unless you have a very specific reason not to, you should keep it in a single table.

Comment: This, and if you want to select based on the field for multiple tables you'll have to duplicate the conditions.

Comment: Okay, but I need to check if the record is available in all tables. So I need to pass the where condition in `login_tb2.code = ... ` ?

Comment: No problem @Jdoe, happy coding ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Code column would be part of more than one table.
in this case prefix with anyone of the table..
e.g login_tb1.code

this would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell mysql which `code` column to use. 
Apparently,  that column appears in more than one table, so for each table you want to check the code column,  write it like this: 
`tablename.code`

This way mysql will know which column to use

I also suggest taking a look at your ta le structure, since having 3 tables with the same structure seems weird. 
You can post a question a out the as well or elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

There are similar columns in the tables. You need to properly alias the table

```
$Query = "SELECT t1.col,t2.col,t3.col FROM login_tb1 as t1, 
login_tb2 as t2, login_tb3 as t3
                  WHERE (t1.code = '".mysql_real_escape_string($code)."') OR 
                        (t2.email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."') ";
```